# date time picker on lotus domino vs localhost

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In my web application, I have developed a date picker for the field and I would like to show date format as dd/mm/yyyy, this works well in localhost as I modified javascript parameter to "dmy" and I repicated to server but on server application it shows mm/dd/yyyy format only, when on server I put follwing formula on on test field to know what is format of server

```
@now([server time]);
```

It shows mm/dd/yyyy format. is this reason why on domino server application it shows as mm/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/mm//yyyy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domino probably got the regional settings from server's operating system. Check Web User Preferences section of the Domino Web Engine tab in internet sites document. You can read about it here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21144507.

If you are not allowed to change server settings, use this formula to display dates:

```
@Text(@Day(_DateField)) + "/" + @Text(@Month(_DateField)) + "/" + @Text(@Year(_DateField))
```